# What is different binding and duration of mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have log from laravel that showing the binding time and duration time of query execution:

```
select * from `yg_product_detail` where `product_id` = '5551973459553' and `yg_product_detail`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1 

Metadata
Bindings 0. 55197345953
Hints    Use SELECT * only if you need all columns from table 
         LIMIT without ORDER BY causes non-deterministic results, depending on the query exection plan

Duration 26.8s
```

And as seen above, my duration time is too long, but I need to make sure, is the duration time the real time from mysql query? or process logic between another query?

because when I try to run those query to mysql, its run fast.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Bindings are values inserted into your SQL query. The execution time displayed on the upper right corner is the actual round-trip time the SQL query took to execute (i.e. the time elapsed between sending the query to the DBMS and the DBMS returning the result as well as parsing the result into models).

If you have an Eloquent query like this:

```
User::where('name', 'like', '%john%')
    ->orderBy('age')
    ->get();
```

Then it will be converted to a prepared SQL statement like this:

```
select *
from `users`
where `name` like ?
order by `age`
```

where the `?` gets replaced by a binding, in this case `'%john%'`. In your case, the binding is the `product_id` which you attempted to cross out in the query but left in the query explanation table.